What is the probability that the last drawn ball is white in this generalized urn problem?
An urn contain balls of $k$ different colors. There are $n_i$ balls of color $i$. Let color 1 be white. All draws are uniformly at random. We perform "turns" until all balls are gone. A turn begins with drawing a first ball. Keep drawing more balls as long as the drawn balls are the same color as the first ball drawn this turn. Once a ball of a different color is drawn (or there are no balls left), return the different colored ball to the urn (unless the urn is empty and all drawn balls are the same color), and the turn is over. Note that all the balls permanently removed from the urn in a given turn are the same color. What is the probability that the last ball drawn from the urn is white?
This is a generalization of the two-color version where the probability is 1/2, no matter how many balls of each color are in the urn (as long as $n_1$ and $n_2$ are non-zero).
Let $p(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k)$ be the required probability. Let $n=\sum_{i=1}^k n_i$. The probability that we will pull exactly $j$ balls of color $i$ followed by a ball of a different color is $\frac{n_i \choose j}{n \choose j}\frac{n-n_i}{n-j}$. Then
$p(n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_k) = \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^{n_i} \frac{n_i \choose j}{n \choose j}\frac{n-n_i}{n-j}p(n_1,\ldots,n_{i-1},n_i-j,n_{i+1},\ldots,n_k)$ for all $n_i>0$,
$p(n_1,0,\ldots,0)=1$ for $n_1>0$, and
$p(0,n_2,n_3,\ldots,n_k)=0$ for at least one non-zero $n_i$.
The equations above make it easy to compute the probability in specific cases, but I'd prefer a closed-form expression for the probability.
I have some partial results for the 3-color case. For example, in the limit as $m \to \infty$,
$p(1,x,m)=2^{-2x}({2x-1 \choose x}+\frac{1}{6}{2x \choose x+1})$,
$p(x,1,m)=\frac{1}{2}-2^{-2x}({2x-1 \choose x}-\frac{1}{6}{2x \choose x+1})$, and
$p(m,1,x)=\frac{1}{2}-2^{-2x}(\frac{1}{3}{2x \choose x+1})$
I find the lack of advantage of having $n_1$ large to be interesting. For example, even as $x \to \infty$, $p(x,1,1)$ never exceeds 5/12. This result seems very surprising initially.

I tried to clarify the question.

The modified description is quite clear and matches the formula.

For reference (in case it helps someone answer this question), here's an instance of the two-color version of this problem: Find probability that last drawn ball is white.

Considering that $p(x,1)$ is identically $1/2$ in the two-color case, I'm not so surprised that the limit of $p(x,1,1)$ is less than $1.$ What surprised me was that I found things such as $p(4,1,4)>p(4,1,3)$ (if I computed them correctly), that is, cases where adding a ball of a different color causes white to be more likely to be the last ball.

Let P(a,b,c) be the triple (p(a,b,c),p(b,c,a),p(c,a,b)). I get 1792P(4,1,3)=(684,442,666), and 1792P(4,1,4)=(687,418,687). It seems that adding the 4th ball of the 3rd color reduces the 2nd color's chances, and both other colors benefit (to differing degrees).
